# Writing a regular expression, better solutions

Tags: python, regex

I want to capture the two times in this string

```
u'11:00 a.m. - 6:00 p.m.'
#ideally to
('11:00', 'a.m'), (6:00,)
```

Right now, I have

```
(\d{1,2}:\d{2})\s(\w\.\w).+(\d{1,2}:\d{2})\s(\S+)
# result
[u'11:00', u'a.m', u'6:00', u'p.m.']
```

Which is ok, I guess. But regular expressions are not one of my superpowers and I'm wondering if there are better ways to capture the info from this string.

Edit: My emphasis on a better regex, not rearranging the list to desired tuple.

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply split the string according to `-` and then:

```
# first part
'11:00 a.m.'.replace('a.m.', 'AM')

# second part (after split you'll have it as a variable and not hardcoded)
'11:00 p.m.'.replace('p.m.', 'PM')
```

And then simply:

```
datetime.strptime(first_date, '%H:%M %p')
datetime.strptime(second_date, '%H:%M %p')
```

---

You can also use `arrow` module (`pip install arrow`):

```
a = arrow.get('11:12 AM', 'HH:mm A')
```

And now all information available:

```
a.hour
>>> 11
a.minute
>>> 12
```

See the [documentation](http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/) for details.

Comment: this is a very nice method. The problem is that datetime inserts the year of 1900 which I think can confuse the users of my program. What would you suggest for that?

Answer (score 2):

Use the findall method with this pattern:

```
re.findall(r'(\d{1,2}:\d\d)\s([ap]\.m\.)', yourstring)
```

Comment: @iharob: read the question one more time. he asked "a better way to capture"

Answer (score 0):

It is not a better way, there are no better ways, but you can do this

```
x = u'11:00 a.m. - 6:00 p.m.'.split()
del x[2]
```